# How to check existing row before deleting row in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I have two tables:

```
// table1                              // table2
+----+------+---------+                +----+------+
| id | col1 | user_id |                | id | col2 |
+----+------+---------+                +----+------+
| 1  | a    | 100001  |                | 1  | a    |
| 2  | b    | 100002  |                | 2  | b    |
| 3  | c    | 100003  |                | 3  | c    |
+----+------+---------+                | 4  | a    |
                                       | 5  | a    |
                                       | 6  | c    |
                                       +----+------+
```

Also I have a variable named `$user_id`. Now I want to delete all row in the `table2` where `col2='a'`, But I need to check `table1.user_id = $user_id` (in this case `$user_id = '100001'` ) in the `table1` before deleting.

How can I write a correct syntax query with this concept:

```
IF table1.user_id = $user_id where table1.col1 = 'a' then
   delete from table2 where col2 = 'a'
```

I can do that using PHP and MySQL using two separated query. But I want to do that with one query, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JOIN to do the delete operation something as

```
delete t2 from table2 t2
join table1 t1 on t2.col2 = t1.col1
where 
t2.col2 = 'a'
and t1.user_id = '100001'
```

Comment: ah, but can you tell me your query will remove what rows exactly?! just `all rows from table2 where col2='a'` ??

Comment: The query logic is find the rows from table by joining the col2 with col1 of table1, then check if col2 = 'a' and table1 user_id is the given input. So it has to match the record with the specified condition and then delete from table2.

Comment: look, your solution is great, but because I use trigger, there is collision in `join` and `delete`, and I can not use `join` in this case. so I want to know, there is a way for using `IF` this condition is true: `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE user_id ='100001' LIMIT 1)`, `THEN` run `DELETE` query ?

Comment: No you can not use if-else in the query, unless the query is a part of trigger or stored procedure.